# Creating database table from tab delimited text file with first row labels

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tab delimited text file with the first row being label headings that are also tab delimited, for example:

```
Name    ID    Money
Tom    239482    $2093984
Barry    293984    $92938
```

The only problem is that there are 30 some columns instead of 3 so I'd rather not have to type out all the (name VARCHAR(50),...) if it's avoidable.

How would I go about writing a function that creates the table from scratch in php from the text file, and say the function takes in $file_path and $table_name? Do I have to write all the column names again telling mysql what type they are and chop off the top or is there a more elegant solution when the names are already there?

Comment: Thanks everyone, at least I'm not still googling for a easy solution; I started writing a parser for it and about 10 regexes in I realized it's a better use of time to just type it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would somehow need to map the column type to the columns in your file. You could do this by adding that data to your textfile. For instance

```
Name|varchar(32)    ID|int(8)    Money|int(10)
Tom    239482    $2093984
Barry    293984    $92938
```

or something similar. Then write a function thet get's the column name and columntype using the first line and the data to fill the table with using all the other rows. You might also want to add a way to name the given table etc. However, this would probably be as much work (if not more) than creating **SQL queries** using you text file. Add a **create table** statement at the top and **insert statements** for each line. With search and replace this could be done very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could find a way to do this, how would you determine the column type? I guess there would be *some* way to determine the type of the columns through checking for certain attributes (int, string, etc). And then you'd need to handle weird columns like Money, which might be seen as a string because of the dollar sign, but should almost certainly be stored as an integer.

Unless you plan on using this function quite a bit, I wouldn't bother spending time cobbling it together. Just fat finger the table creation. (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V is your friend)